# Android Google maps how to zoom to a specific area

Tags: android, onclick, android-activity, zooming

I have 2 different activities: On the first one i have my map and I am doing something else on the second one. I have a button on the second activity and I want that button to display a specific area on the map when it's clicked. But my code stops the app when I click the button. The weird thing is that if I remove the 2 lines of code above cameraUpdate, when the button is clicked, it just takes me to the other acitivity displaying the map, but I want it to zoom on a specific area, which it doesn't.

```
public void show_map(View x){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), THEMAP.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_AMERICA,13);
    gMap.animateCamera(update);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be placing your code to manipulate the map in the `Activity` that actually contains the map, not in the launching `Activity`. You'd need to post more of your code for me to be sure, but try moving

```
CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_AMERICA,13);
gMap.animateCamera(update);
```

into your `onCreate()` in `THEMAP` (not your actual class name I hope.

Comment: so if I have 5 different items that I want to display on the map in different locations how is that possible to be implemented ? Do I need 5 different activities showing the cameraupdate for each one in a different activity ?

Comment: If you just have one map, then you only need one `Activity` to display that map and everything on it.